# Migrate SP2013 Enterprise to New Farm with SP2013 Standard with new SQL Server

Tags: 2013, migration, restore, spsite

I was hoping to get some advice on the best way to migrate from an Existing SharePoint 2013 Enterprise Farm, to a completely new Farm running SharePoint 2013 Standard.

I will need to migrate User Profile / MySites / Publishing Content and wondered if this is possible across different versions easily?

UPDATE:

I have hit a specific issue trying to restore a site collection

> Restore-SPSite :
>   0x80070003
>
> Directory Not Found

A lot of people have mentioned version numbers needing to match.

The farm versions are as follows:

Current (SP2013 Enterprise): Major 15 minor 0 build 4420 revision 1017 (RTM)

New (SP2013 Standard): Major 15 minor 0 build 4569  revision 1000 (SP1)

Can anyone confirm if these version numbers need to match exactly and if so, is that possible when one is running enterprise and one is on standard?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If you feel confident in your abilities, you can try the Database Detach and Attach move as Waqas mentioned above.

Using a third-party migration tool would most likely be the easiest way. Especially since the version numbers would not be a factor.

Most of the major players in that market offer free trial so you can get a good idea of their different features.

Answer (score 0):

I am confident, this is not supported approach, what i believe you have to uninstall the Enterprise on your source farm.

Build new Farm, Move the Database to new farm and attach them
Run Full sync & full crawl.

Have a look on this article; http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262747.aspx

or I would also check the 3rd party tools i.e Metalogix, AvePoint, ShareGate.